Visual Studio C++: copy projects and solutions from one pc to another (github not working)
Visual Studio C++: copy projects and solutions from one pc to another (github not working):
Can I just copy these files to another pc? Or will I mess things up (e.g. in github)? On the destination pc, github is not connected/not working/not available.
So I guess this will just create a branch-less solution.
At which level to copy? What files to (not) copy?




You don't need github, you can configure git on the "new" computer to use the "old" as a remote and use git in the normal way.

@molbdnilo There is no "Git" tab in VS on the new computer. No idea why.

You don't need VS to use Git. Install Git and clone the repo using the command line or use a GUI client.

The likely reason for a lack of Git tab in VS is a lack of Git install on that machine. Are you able to run the VS installer to modify the install?

@Caleth: you are right, but it's complicated with admin rights at work and a colleague owning the machine, so I just wanted to handle it quickly with a manual copy

What's the purpose of getting this code onto the machine that lacks Git? If any changes are made, you are going to have to manually copy back to a machine with Git installed, or install Git anyway

@Caleth: True. Goal: quickly test if the the issues I have are related to network instability or not.

In addition, make sure you have the same C++ runtime installed on new computer.

You can absolutely copy the whole repository contents to a different computer, that's what Git does. In your case that would be the source/repos/ctool folder. If Git is then installed onto that computer, it will treat it like the repository on the source computer.
You can safely ignore copying any files mentioned in the .gitignore file, which probably includes the everything in x64/Debug.

Thanks. In this case I would do it manually with just a windows copy paste action.
